# Why I can change cell's frame in viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, tableview

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.cell4.frame = CGRectMake(self.cell4.frame.origin.x, self.cell4.frame.origin.y, self.cell4.frame.size.width, self.cell4.frame.size.height + 60);
    self.cell5.frame = CGRectMake(self.cell5.frame.origin.x, self.cell5.frame.origin.y + 60, self.cell5.frame.size.width, self.cell5.frame.size.height);
}
```

I found the cell's frame has changed, but in ui it does not change. Is there any work should do?

Comment: @Larme yes,I add [self.tableView reloadData] but no use

Comment: I didn't try, but check if `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called after the `viewWillAppear` which could be the reason.

Comment: @Larme I think change cell's height in init should use heightForRowAtIndexPath. I have fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write code in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // set cell's height yourself

}
```

will fix it.